# Finding eigenvalues and eigenspaces for the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is a matrix that reflects vectors *x* $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ about a fixed plane *P* in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find all eigenvalues and eigenspaces of A.  Does A admit an eigenbasis for $\mathbb{R}^3$? Why or why not?

Another part of this question: Let ***a*** = $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & \beta & \gamma \end{bmatrix}^T$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^3$ be nonzero and fixed.  Consider the linear transformation *T* : $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by *T*(***x***) = ***a*** $\times$ ***x***. Find all real eigenvalues of *T* and all real eigenspaces of *T*.  Does *T* admit an eigenbasis for $\mathbb{R}^3$? Why or why not?

for the first part I don't know how I would find an eigenvalue for a matrix I don't know, I would assume A would look like a *reflection* matrix but I've looked online and I can't find anything that tells me what a 3$\times$3 reflection matrix would look like.

for the second part, I know that ***a*** would look like $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\ \beta \\\ \gamma \end{bmatrix}$, but wouldn't ***a*** $\times$ ***x*** look like $\begin{bmatrix}\beta x_3 - \gamma x_2 & \gamma x_1 - \alpha x_3 & \alpha x_2 - \beta x_1 \end{bmatrix}$? And if so how would you even find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of that?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: maybe this would help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014103/matrix-of-reflection-in-r3 (reflection matrix definition)

Comment: so the reflection matrix would just be the map (x1,x2,x3) --> (x1, x2, -x3)?

Comment: A hint for the construction of $A$: do you know what it looks like when reflecting about the $xy$ or $yz$ or $xz$ plane?

Comment: @grace You wrote the example of a reflection about the $xy$ plane. In the question, a general fixed plane $P$ is used.

Comment: no, we're given nothing but what the question states... Which is why I was thinking we'd construct it with vectors x like it says in the question; would it just be a diagonal matrix with values x1, x2, -x3?

Comment: @Karlo would we just use u and v instead of x and y?

Comment: You might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605489/81360) helpful. If $v$ is a vector perpendicular to $P$, then $A = I - 2vv^T$ is the reflection matrix for that first part.

Comment: is it okay to just use a perpendicular vector v? or do I need to generalize it for any vector x?

Comment: also @Omnomnomnom when I find A using the equation you suggested and try to find the eigenvalue it's a really crazy equation with (v1+v2+v3) as a factor of some of the terms and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right...

Comment: @grace I wouldn't use the matrix to compute the eigenvalues. I'll put together a detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to doing this problem efficiently is to understand the geometric interpretation of an eigenvalue. Recall that for a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$, we say that $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is an eigenvector of $T$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ if it is a non-zero vector for which $T(x) = \lambda x$.

For the first problem, our linear transformation is $T_A(x) = Ax$. It is given that $T$ takes a vector and reflects it across the plane $P$. Suppose that $v_1$ is a non-zero vector perpendicular to $P$.

- I claim that $v_1$ must be an eigenvector of $T_A$. Do you see why? What is the eigenvalue associated with $v_1$?
- Take any two linearly independent vectors $v_2,v_3$ that are orthogonal to $v_1$ (that is, two vectors from the plane $P$).  I claim that these are also eigenvectors. Do you see why? What are the associated eigenvalues?
- $v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$, and each vector is an eigenvector. So, $A$ admits an eigenbasis for $\Bbb R^3$.

For the second problem, our linear transformation is $T(x) = \alpha \times x$.

- By the properties of the cross product, $T(x)$ must be orthogonal to $x$.  There is exactly one real number $\lambda$ for which it is possible to have $x \neq 0$ and $T(x) = \lambda x$, what is this $\lambda$? If $x$ is an eigenvector associated with this $\lambda$, what must be true about $x$?
- From the above, we have found out that $T$ has only one real eigenvalue, and the eigenspace associated with that eigenvalue is $1$-dimensional. Since we have no more eigenvectors with which to construct an eigenbasis, we conclude that $T$ does not admit an eigenbasis for $\Bbb R^3$.

---

As I explained above, using the specific entries for the matrices associated with these transformations turns out not to be a "nice" approach. If you are interested in seeing what these matrices might look like, then you should know that the reflection matrix from the first part is the [Householer transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) $A = I - 2vv^T$, and the cross-product matrix for the second part is $[\alpha]_{\times}$, as is explained in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) of the cross-product wiki page.

Comment: would the eigenvalue associated with v1 be -1, since it's being reflected across P? or would it be just 1 since that's the magnitude with which it is stretched (or reflected)? for v2 and v3 would their eigenvalues just be 1 since they're not being transformed at all?

Comment: @grace You were right the first time; the eigenvalue would be $-1$. We want to keep track of the sign of the eigenvalue, so the reflection aspect is important.  And for $v_2,v_3,$ the eigenvalues are indeed both just $1$.

Comment: For the sec\ond part, it must be that $\lambda=0$, how else could $\lambda x = \alpha \times x$, I mean $\alpha \times x$ is perpindicular to $x$!!! So $\lambda=0$ and so $x=0$, is this right? 

If $x=0$ is our only eigen vector, then is it right to say that this vector spans a 1 dimensional eigenspace?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa There is in fact a non-zero vector $x$ for which $\alpha \times x  =0$

Comment: for the first part I don't see exactly *why* v1, v2, and v3 must be eigenvectors of $T_A$.. is it because we have an eigenvalue associated with all of them?

Comment: @grace That's exactly it. What it means for $x$ to be an eigenvector is that $x \neq 0$ and there is a $\lambda$ such that $T$ just multiplies $x$ by $\lambda$.

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa Technically I should say that $\alpha \times x$ is *orthogonal* to $x$, since $\alpha \times x$ might be zero

Comment: for the second part would $\lambda$ be -1 since the cross product of two parallel vectors is 0?

Comment: @grace it's true that the cross product of parallel vectors is zero and this is indeed the key point, but how did you get $\lambda = -1$?

Comment: i figured that it could be pointing in the opposite direction, but it could also be pointing in the same direction

Comment: Ignore the sign for now. What should the *magnitude* of $\lambda$ be? That is, "how much longer/shorter" is the new vector $T(x)$?

Comment: would it be 1 because it's not changing length?

Comment: @grace but it is changing length! If $\mathbf x$ is non-zero, then its length is non-zero. However, $T(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$, so surely the length of $\mathbf x$ is different than the length of $T(\mathbf x)$.

Comment: oh is lambda 0?

Comment: @grace Yes, that's exactly right! And the eigenspace is one dimensional because every eigenvector (associated with $0$) would have to be parallel to (i.e. a multiple of) $\mathbf{\alpha}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh my god that makes so much sense. Seriously, thank you so much!

Comment: @grace you're welcome